# CPU sitting at lowest clock speed when pstates is disbled

Tags: cpu

So in order to have more control over CPU with [cpufreq](https://github.com/konkor/cpufreq) I need to disable pstates so it uses acpi. Now when I add "intel_pstate=disable" to grub and reboot it boot but stay on ~700MHz frequency when I try to change it via cpufreq gui of via terminal but it doesn't change. When pstates is not diabled I can use cpufreq but only to set to performance or ondemand with it disabled it offers more options but doesn't work. Note in install document it says I should disable pstates.

Here is screenshot with pstates disabled.

[image]

My CPU is i5 2520m if that matters.

Comment: Your processor seems to be running at below its normal minimum, which means that Clock Modulation might be involved. It is a Dell LapTop and is it using a Dell AC adapter? The intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver does not have the ondemand governor.  What install document said to disable the intel_pstate driver? My input is to ignore those instructions and use it with the powersave governor. For the acpi-cpufreq driver you are using the userspace governor, which seems to be clamped at the minimum for the processor, so at least use another governor if you insist on using that driver.

Comment: Yes it's Dell laptop with Dell adapter. Sorry not ondemand, but powersave and performance. Yes on screenshot it's userspace because I was switching governors to see if any is going to have affect on clock speed and it doesn't, it's just happened that screenshot is taken when that governor was active.

Comment: O.K. At least for a test, set the performance governor (doesn't matter which driver), put a 100% load on one CPU and observe and tell us the CPU frequency. Please be aware that if the load is light enough the CPU frequency will drop, regardless of the governor. The suggested monitoring tool for this stuff is turbostat (included in the linux-tools-common package). I like this command: `sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,IRQ --interval 15`. Also need to figure out why Clock Modulation seems to be involved.

Comment: Here is performance governor with acpi. What I've done is let blender render image on 1280 samples and it wouldn't move, I couldn't let it more because using pc was impossible. I know if load is light clock speed is low, but everything I try to do takes too long starting nautilus 10 seconds, it just won't raise clock speed, starting firefox is royal pain in the ass. https://i.postimg.cc/vZcyGkHR/Screenshot-from-2019-03-16-16-55-26.png

Comment: Given that your processor is at 55 degrees while only consuming 6.5 watts, my best guess is that at some point it got too hot, and Clock Modulation was engaged. Are you running thermald and/or tlp? If you run the turbostat command without the --quiet option, there might be some thermal trip information in the bunch of detail that it prints at startup.

Comment: Temperature doesn't go any further on lower no matter what I do, so there is that. No I would guess not unless thermald is enabled by default on kernel. Is there a way to disable Clock modulation?

Comment: Here are screenshots from terminal since I don't actually know what to look for. https://i.postimg.cc/rpWXdfyZ/Screenshot-from-2019-03-16-19-01-39.png  https://i.postimg.cc/50Vc8864/Screenshot-from-2019-03-16-19-01-50.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91133/discussion-between-doug-smythies-and-black-cloud).